# How to embed an OpenLayers map in a blog post?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, osgeo

I have a map in GeoServer which I need to publish in a blog post.

I'm pretty sure this is possible but I am not managing to make it work.

I'm posting the html source code from the openlayers layer preview I get from geoserver, but not getting the map...

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: what about putting the map in a separate page and in blog page add it with iframe ?? How's that sound ?

Comment: could be an option...but not the ideal for me...

Comment: I've given a general idea for this,please share some code,provide some additional details so we can help better.People cannot know your ideals !

Comment: please check the page source of http://ligabernardino.com/teste/teste.html

Comment: did you notice that the page has lots of script errors depending on OpenLayers.js that needs other scripts to load with full functionality,Please change your openlayers.js file with regular one without debug files or add other script files in responsive directory.

Comment: OK, I did that, but still have no map... :(

Comment: No,I can clearly see the map on the page.